# Python script that executes another python script

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to the world of python. I decided to do a project but came to a stop, after my script wouldn't execute the right way. In which I mean the script that I need to be executed on its own through another script keeps on giving me nothing or some syntax error instead of all the stuff that is supposed to be happening (converting files). The other script in question writes new lines into the other script to change the file name (to be converted) to the newest file. The file looks something like this:

```
import glob
import os.path

folder_path = r'C:\User\Desktop\Folder\Audio'
file_type = r'\*mp4'
files = glob.glob(folder_path + file_type)
max_file = max(files, key=os.path.getctime)

mp3_file = max_file.replace('.mp4', '')

with open ("file.py", 'w') as f:
    f.write("")

with open ("file.py", 'w') as f:
    f.write('from moviepy.editor import *\n' "mp4_file = '{}'\n"
"mp3_file = '{}.mp3'\n" 'videoclip = VideoFileClip(mp4_file)\n' 'audioclip = videoclip.audio\n'
'audioclip.write_audiofile(mp3_file)\n' 'audioclip.close()\n' 'videoclip.close()\n'.format(max_file, mp3_file))

exec(open("file.py").read())
```

Right now it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Folder\Audio\File Manager.py", line 19, in <module>
    exec(open("file.py").read())
  File "<string>", line 2
    mp4_file = 'C:\User\Desktop\Folder\Audio\test.mp4'
                                                                ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

I plan not on using that exact line of code to execute my python file since there are many alternatives, but if I was on the right trail, then I might as well. The other file that's supposed to be executed has generic file converting code:

```
from moviepy.editor import *
mp4_file = 'C:\User\Desktop\Folder\Audio\test.mp4'
mp3_file = 'C:\User\Desktop\Folder\Audio\test.mp3'
videoclip = VideoFileClip(mp4_file)
audioclip = videoclip.audio
audioclip.write_audiofile(mp3_file)
audioclip.close()
videoclip.close()
```

Other solutions mostly gave me a blank inactive shell; if the answer to this problem that it's impossible, then it might as well be, and I'll take that as a valid answer, but please explain why.

Comment: Why not just write the other file's code as a function in your `File Manager.py` file and call it while passing the values as arguments?

Comment: Also no need to write it to a file, simply put it in a variable and use `exec(variable)` to execute the code. Not sure why you are complicating a simple task.

Comment: Why do you want to dynamically write a script file and execute that, instead of just adding those lines to your script? If you insist on doing it that way, perhaps using https://docs.python.org/3/library/runpy.html#runpy.run_path would be easier than `exec`

Answer (score 0):

### Corrections

1. You are using different quotes while writing to the file, from single quotes `'` to double `"`, update it to be more consistent.
2. The error is suggesting that while writing to the file it is also writing some `unicode` characters which it cannot read hence the `unicode error` (look at where the carrot `^` is pointing at, it's a blank space since it's not a printable character).

### Suggestions

1. Don't just write to a file and then immediately read from it. Different operating systems have different behaviour for such repeated access which will give you strange issues (this is not your issue tho)
2. Just create a function `extractMp3FromVideoFile` which takes two arguements `max_file` and `mp3_file`
3. Instead of writing to a file and increasing the HDD IO simply put the file's code into a variable and then `exec` it.

### Solution

```py
import glob
import os.path

folder_path = r'C:\User\Desktop\Folder\Audio'
file_type = r'\*mp4'
files = glob.glob(folder_path + file_type)
max_file = max(files, key=os.path.getctime)

mp3_file = max_file.replace('.mp4', '')

code = "from moviepy.editor import *\nmp4_file = '{}'\nmp3_file = '{}.mp3'\nvideoclip = VideoFileClip(mp4_file)\naudioclip = videoclip.audio\naudioclip.write_audiofile(mp3_file)\naudioclip.close()\nvideoclip.close()\n".format(max_file, mp3_file)

exec(code)
```